# PayPal cert on web server

Tags: asp.net, ssl, paypal, x509certificate

I have an existing web app that uses the PayPal Payments Standard SOAP environment. It's been running on IIS for years now. I'm migrating to a new server (Windows Server 2012), but can't place any PayPal transactions (PayPal or Direct Payment). I'm getting a "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive." error.

I know the issue is that PayPal is rejecting my certificate, but I can't figure out WHY.

I've created the .P12 and exported to a .CER. I believe everything is set up properly in the certificate store.

Anyone know where there is documentation on how to set up IIS (v8.5) for an asp.net app?? Or any ideas what my problem is??

Comment: Why not just use the Signature method instead of Certificate?  It's a lot easier.

Comment: What's the "signature method"?? I can find a few references to it, but nothing that explains what it is or how to use it.

Comment: Instead of messing with certificates you just include a user, password, and signature value in your API request.  There is [more info about it here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/) under the "Specifying an API Credential Using Signatures" section.

Comment: I don't believe I can use that with Direct (credit card) Payments.

Comment: Yes you can.  It works with any of the classic APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it does look promising, but, right now I need to get the certificate working as I have a live site right now that is working with the certificate. If I request signature credentials for my new server, I suspect I won't be able to keep my old server running with the certificate - so, I'm kind of stuck with the certificate. My old server is running Windows Server 2008 and the new server is Windows Server 2012 - it's the exact code and the certificate is registered (I think) exactly the same. I don't know why I can't get the new server running.

Comment: You are correct that once you switch to signature you lose the certificate, but it would only take a moment to get your current site switched to signature.  It's simply adding 1 extra parameter to your API requests.  Unfortunately, I don't have any tips for the certificate.

Comment: Appreciate your help! I wrote this code MANY years ago when they only had the certificate authorization - when PayPal first initiated their API. I probably would have to re-write a bunch of code if I change as well, so I'm not too anxious to make a change if I don't have to. Somehow, I need to figure out why I can't process a direct payment on the new server - the code works on my development computer, as well as the old server. I've been working on this problem for 3 days now, and have exhausted everything I can think of!

Comment: I finally figured it out. The identity of the ApplicationPools in IIS under Windows 2012 are assigned to the user: ApplicationPoolIdentity (earlier versions where assigned to "NetworkService"). I created a new ApplicationPool and set the identity to "Network Service" and it works now.

It only took the whole weekend plus Friday (I did take breaks in-between to clear my head) to finally figure this out.